# Auto detect hosts using Nagios

Tags: linux, networking

Is it possible to configure Nagios to auto detect all the hosts that belong to the network and auto configure the .cfg files? Thanks.

Comment: The original Nagios Core can't do that. Maybe there is a plugin or external script...

Answer (score 2):

The front-end Centreon can do that ( http://www.centreon.com/ )
You can also take a look around Observium ( http://www.observium.org/wiki/Main_Page )